# JSON is an object of strings - but I need the last member of the JSON to be a byte array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, post, mapping

I've got a web service that "listens" for an HTTP POST request that sends JSON data- here's the start of the method that does this:

```
// POST api/blah
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage PostPicture(HttpRequestMessage msg)
{
    string data = msg.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
...
```

The variable "data" contains the raw JSON, and by nature, it's just a string that's formatted as JSON.  Here is the variable "data":

```
{
  "longitude" : 96.84610000000001,
  "latitude" : 35.5608,
  "username" : "mgallow",
  "imageDataBlob" : "\/9j\/4UI5RXhpZgAASUkqAAg..... and so on
}
```

In the end, I'm taking this data and inserting it into the database- Longitude and Latitude are of type decimal, username is of type nvarchar(50), and imageDataBlob is of type varbinary(MAX).  The code below, in the same method, is taking that JSON data and deserializing it into an object of type "Picture", which is what represents my table in the database:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage PostPicture(HttpRequestMessage msg)
{
    string data = msg.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

    Picture obj = Activator.CreateInstance<Picture>();

    using (MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(data)))
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());
        obj = (Picture)serializer.ReadObject(stream1);
    }
    ...
```

But the error I'm getting, and I understand why I'm getting it, is:

> There was an error deserializing the object of type
>   blah.Models.Picture. End element 'imageDataBlob' from namespace
>   '' expected. Found text '/'.

Research indicates this is beacuse it's expecting a varbinary, but instead getting a string (from the JSON).  As part of my testing, I changed the data type in my table to an nvarchar(MAX), and I didn't get that error anymore.

**My question is:**

How can I take the JSON that comes through as a string, and get it to map correctly to my object, which is a mix of string, decimal, and byte[]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `imageDataBlob` field seems to be base64 encoded. Declare it as *string* in your `Picture` class and then use `Convert.FromBase64String`

Comment: It says that this string isn't a valid Base64 string due to illegal characters.  Here's the first part of this huge string, which I believe contains the "illegal" characters..

\/9j\/4UI5RXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAKAA8BAgASAAAAhgAAABABAgALAAAAmAAA\nABo

Answer (score 1):

Look at base64 encoding - that should give you some ideas...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to do a Base64 encode on the data before forming the JSON . Similarly you can decode the data in the server side before updating it in to database.